# How to read all data from druid datasource

Tags: hadoop, datasource, druid

I am using below json to read all data from a druid datasource.
    But in the request threshold field/value is mandatory.
    It returns number of rows specified in threshold.

```
{
  "queryType" : "select",
  "dataSource" : "wikiticker",
  "granularity" : "day",
  "intervals" : [ "1000/3000" ],
  "filter" :null,
  "dimensions" : [ ],
  "metrics" : [ ],
  "descending" : "false",
  "pagingSpec" : {
    "threshold" : 10000,
    "pagingIdentifiers" : null
  },
  "aggregations" : [ ]
}
```

Is there any way to retrieve all the data by setting the threshold to some value that returns all the data from datasource.

```
For eg:if intervals column is set to [ "1000/3000" ] gets data from all intervals.
```

Answer (score 1):

The distributed nature of the system makes it hard to have an exact count of rows per interval of time, therefor the answer is no. Also keep in mind that select query will materialize all the rows in-memory so you might want to avoid pulling all the data at once and use pagination spec.